# VB.NET 2010: query complex XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I'm a long time reader of the site, recently began contributing; this is my first real question that I can't find any "close to working" examples that I can work with.  I'm working with a large (15m), complex XML file retrieved via a web service and I'm trying to get a "per site employee with punches" count.  Anything that gets me closer to getting there is a big help.

The XML file has a layout like so:

```
<AllCards ReportCount="39">
<response>
    <CardReport>
        <BeginDate>2015-09-01</BeginDate>
        <EndDate>2015-09-30</EndDate>
        <Site>
            <SiteNumber>000001</SiteNumber>
            <ClientTag>9999</ClientTag>
            <SiteName>A Name Goes here</SiteName>
            <UseMinuteRounding>0</UseMinuteRounding>
            <Xdefinition>Job</Xdefinition>
            <PayCodes>01|02|06|07|05|08|04</PayCodes>
            <PayCodeCategories>Regular|Overtime|Sick|Holiday|Vacation|Psersonal</PayCodeCategories>
            <DateTimeUTC>2015-10-20T20:34:06</DateTimeUTC>
            <DateTimeSiteLocal>2015-10-20T16:34:06</DateTimeSiteLocal>
        </Site>
        <Cards/>
    </CardReport>
</response>
```

This client has no employees with cards, thus would return a 0.  This client has employees with punches:

```
<response>
    <CardReport>
        <BeginDate>2015-09-01</BeginDate>
        <EndDate>2015-09-30</EndDate>
        <Site>
            <SiteNumber>000002</SiteNumber>
            <ClientTag>9998</ClientTag>
            <SiteName>Another Name</SiteName>
            <UseMinuteRounding>0</UseMinuteRounding>
            <PayCodes>01|02|07|06|04|05|08|04|04</PayCodes>
            <PayCodeCategories>Regular|Overtime|Holiday|Sick|Other|Vacation|Personal|Misc</PayCodeCategories>
            <DateTimeUTC>2015-10-20T20:34:07</DateTimeUTC>
            <DateTimeSiteLocal>2015-10-20T16:34:07</DateTimeSiteLocal>
        </Site>
        <Cards>
            <Card>
                <Employee>
                    <UniqueID>999999999</UniqueID>
                    <FullName>Full Name</FullName>
                    <FirstName>Full</FirstName>
                    <LastName>Name</LastName>
                    <SSN>888888888</SSN>
                    <EmployeeCode>22</EmployeeCode>
                    <HomeDepartment>100</HomeDepartment>
                    <PayRate0>37.00</PayRate0>
                    <StartDate>2006-03-08</StartDate>
                </Employee>
                <Punches>
                    <Punch>
                        <id>1141123250</id>
                        <PunchDate>2015-09-01</PunchDate>
                        <InDT>2015-09-01T08:46:02</InDT>
                        <InUnrounded>2015-09-01T08:46:02</InUnrounded>
                        <InUTC>2015-09-01T12:46:02</InUTC>
                        <OutDT>2015-09-01T12:15:39</OutDT>
                        <OutUnrounded>2015-09-01T12:15:39</OutUnrounded>
                        <OutUTC>2015-09-01T16:15:39</OutUTC>
                        <LunchMinutes>0</LunchMinutes>
                        <Hours>3.49</Hours>
                        <NonOTHours>3.49</NonOTHours>
                        <OT1Hours>0</OT1Hours>
                        <OT1Category>Overtime</OT1Category>
                        <OT1PayRate>55.5</OT1PayRate>
                        <OT2Hours>0</OT2Hours>
                        <OT2Category>Doubletime</OT2Category>
                        <OT2PayRate>74</OT2PayRate>
                        <PayRate>37</PayRate>
                        <ApplicablePayRate>37</ApplicablePayRate>
                        <Category>Regular</Category>
                        <Department>100</Department>
                    </Punch>
                </Card>
            </Cards>
        </CardReport>
    </response>
```

There can be any number of employees to a site, one card per employee, any number of punches on a card.  I should also note that this doesn't come formatted for humans, and I've removed a lot of superficial fields for easier posting and reading.

Reading & searching this site, I've come across a few helpful posts, this one being the most useful:

```
Dim sXMLFIle As String = "e:\Test\sitecards.xml"
DataSet1.ReadXml(sXMLFIle)
DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet1
DataGridView1.DataMember = "Site"
```

The DataMember of DataGridView is where I start to get confused.  When I use "response", I see nothing; using "Site", I get a list of sites, "CardReport", just the begin and end dates, "employees" just the employees, all of this leading me to believe that I can only access the elements withing a member, and not the collections contained within that member.  I've tried specifying the path to the data I need;"response/cardreport/cards/employee", but that just errors with "Child list for field ..."

I'm not even sure I'm going about this the right way, or how else I would go about it other then literally parsing the file manually (I read that as very slow / time consuming).

Any hints, pokes or nudges on how to read this file would be great, a bit of code to work with would be even better!

Thanks for reading!
Fred

Comment: Tell me what columns you want in the DataGridView and I will extract the data from the XML.  I know all the tricks.  I prefer to use Xml Linq (XDocument) instead of straight XML (XmlDocument).

Comment: Thanks jdweng.  Using your "I like" idea, I googled and searched here and found working examples of what I needed.  I can see why you prefer it ovr the xmlDocument type.  See below for what I came up with.  Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I really dislike answering my own question, but in this case, thanks to jdweng, I found some examples and created a solution for this particular problem:

```
    'String holding the path to the file we want
    Dim sXMLFIle As String = "e:\Test\sitecards.xml"
    'Load the xdocument with the xml file to work with
    Dim XDdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(sXMLFIle)
    'Prep work: a simple output string for now
    Dim sReport As String = ""
    'for each element called CardReport 
    For Each XLSite As XElement In XDdoc.Descendants("CardReport")
        'specify the complete path to the elements we need to get their values or counts from
        Dim sSiteTWID As String = XLSite.Descendants("Site").Elements("SiteNumber").Value
        Dim sSiteCOID As String = XLSite.Descendants("Site").Elements("ClientTag").Value
        Dim sSiteName As String = XLSite.Descendants("Site").Elements("SiteName").Value
        Dim iCounter As Integer = XLSite.Descendants("Card").LongCount
        'build the temp output string
        sReport &= sSiteTWID & "~~" & sSiteCOID & "~~" & sSiteName & "~~" & CStr(iCounter) & vbCrLf
    Next
    'remove the xddoc object now (due to it's size)
    XDdoc = Nothing
    'Convert the output string into an array for further processing...
    Dim aRpt() As String = Split(sReport, vbCrLf)
```

Ok, so this is what I have, it works, and returns accurate results.  Because I'm always looking to learn, Is there a better way?

Better Way

```css
       Dim results = XDdoc.Descendants("CardReport").Select(Function(x) New With { _
                                                                 .sSiteTWID = x.Descendants("Site").Elements("SiteNumber").Value,
                                                                 .sSiteCOID = x.Descendants("Site").Elements("ClientTag").Value,
                                                                 .sSiteName = x.Descendants("Site").Elements("SiteNumber").Value,
                                                                 .iCounter = x.Descendants("Card").LongCount
                                                             }).ToList()
​
```